# QGIS: Change default options for labels

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, style

Is there a way to change the default options for the labels in the layouts. It is annoying to have to add a frame, background, offset each time when you have multiple labels.

Comment: You could copy/paste your labels after they are styled.

Comment: What do you mean by " labels in the layouts"? Labels are the texts you add to features that appear **on the map** (like names of cities, rivers, countries etc.). You don't add them in the Print Layout, but in the main QGIS window/styling panel / labels. In the Print Layout window, you can add, however, Annotations  (text boxes). So please make clear what you mean - probably add a screenshot.

Comment: Gabriel: Thank you. That does speed things up.

Comment: Babel: They may well be annotations and not labels. Unfortunately, the description associated with adding one of these items says "Adds a new Label to the layout".